# Moving files from one parquet partition to another

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet, hadoop-partitioning

I have a very large amount of data in my S3 bucket partitioned by two columns `MODULE` and `DATE`
such that the file structure of my parquets are:

```
s3://my_bucket/path/file.parquet/MODULE='XYZ'/DATE=2020-01-01
```

I have 7 `MODULE` and the `DATE` ranges from `2020-01-01` to `2020-09-01`.
I found a discrepancy in the data and need to correct the `MODULE` entries for one of the module. Basically I need to change all data for a particular index number, belonging to `MODULE` XYZ to `MODULE` ABC.
I can do this in pyspark by loading the data frame and doing something like:

```
df=df.withColumn('MODULE', when(col('index')==34, "ABC").otherwise(col('MODULE')))
```

But how do I repartition it so that only those entries that are changed get moved to the `ABC MODULE` partition? If I do something like:

```
df.mode('append').partitionBy('MODULE','DATE').parquet(s3://my_bucket/path/file.parquet")
```

I would be adding the data along with the erroneous `MODULE` data. Plus,  I have almost a years worth of data and don't want to repartition the entire dataset as it would take a very long time.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can use the `input_file_name` function to identify the file you need to change, therefore, you can just overwrite these specific files instead of the whole data. That's just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you have data in partition `MODULE=XYZ` that should be moved to `MODULE=ABC`.

First, identify the impacted files.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

file_list = df.where(F.col("index") == 34).select(
    F.input_file_name()
).distinct().collect()
```

Then, you create a dataframe based only on theses files, you use it to complete both `MODULE`.

```py
df = spark.read.parquet(file_list).withColumn(
    "MODULE", when(col("index") == 34, "ABC").otherwise(col("MODULE"))
)

df.write.parquet(
    "s3://my_bucket/path/ABC/", mode="append", partitionBy=["MODULE", "DATE"]
)
```

At this point, ABC should be OK (you just added the missing data), but XYZ should be wrong because of duplicate data. To recover XYZ, you just need to delete the list of files in `file_list`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about `input_file_name()`. 
When you say delete the list of files in `file_list` do you mean manually in the S3 console or CLI? Or programmatically? 
How would I do it programmatically?

Comment: @thentangler for me, this whole script is manual. So, you can use a S3 python lib. Or extract the path list on a file, and create a delete script to paste in S3 console or CLI

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do this by filtering the data for that particular index then save that data with date as partition.

```
df=df.withColumn('MODULE', when(col('index')==34, "ABC").otherwise(col('MODULE')))
df = df.filter(col('index')==34)
df.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('DATE').parquet(s3://my_bucket/path/ABC/")
```

In this way you will only end up modifying only the changed module i.e. ABC

Comment: Thank you for this solution. So I would need to delete the data in module `XYZ` right? As is with the solution provided by Steven above. Can I do that programmatically?